# Validate `<input>` on tab over?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have seen a bunch of JavaScript validation tutorials which validate your input as you type.

E.g.: http://reactiveraven.github.com/jqBootstrapValidation/

However they all seem to be constantly validating, which could prove annoying to end-users.

Can I make it validate only after you've tabbed to the next `<input>`,`<button>` or `<a>`?

[using pure JS, no JQuery or other library]

Comment: Yes, use `blur`, or `onblur`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You'd want to use the `onblur` event on your element.

```
elem.addEventListener('blur', validateInput, false); // validateInput being your validation function
```

Comment: Hmm, I think that's what I'm looking for; though could you show me in a two-field form on JSfiddle just to be certain?

Comment: Note that `blur` will fire *however* the input loses focus, not just through tabbing to another field. That may not matter to the OP, but it *is* different to what was asked

Comment: @Gareth Agreed. If that is the case, `keydown` should be monitored for an `e.which` or `e.keyCode` of `9`, which is the tab key's code.

Comment: Amaan: Perfect @Gareth: This is even more perfect than what I asked for :D